# Finding the 2D pack in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Where is the 2D pack in the Unity store? I can't find it when searching for it. I have tried all the filters and still can't find the app. Here is an image of what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: I think this is what you want https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/73728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Asset Pack**

You have to add it via **Assets/Import Package/2D**

**Sprite Pack**

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/73728

**The 2D Pack itself was deleted**

See: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18684

**You can still download the example games as standalone assets**

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=publisher:1&2d

Comment: Alternatively, Window -> Asset Store -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkZkm.png

Comment: How do I open the Sprite Pack in the Unity app?

Comment: Open the Asset Store -> Click on Import -> A window will open --> Click on Import again -> You'll now have the 2D Sprites in a Folder in your Assets

Comment: I cannot find the Import button in the Asset Store. Where would it be located?